# Do I need to call CompleteMessageAsync when I'm in ReceiveAndDelete mode?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have the following Azure Service Bus code:

```
private async Task startInternalAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(_connectionString);
    try {
        var processor = client.CreateProcessor(_queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions {
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete,
            PrefetchCount = 100
        });

        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += messageHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += errorHandler;

        await processor.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationToken);
        await cancellationToken.WhenCanceled();

        _logger.LogDebug("Cancellation requested.  Stopping the receiver...");
        await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
        _logger.LogDebug("Stopped receiving messages.");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) {
        _logger.LogDebug("Cancellation requested.  Exiting.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        _logger.LogError("Message processing exception.  Exiting.", ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task messageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args) {
    string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
    _logger.LogDebug($"Received msg: {body}");

    // complete the message. message is deleted from the queue.
    await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
}

private async Task errorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args) {
    await Task.Yield();
    _logger.LogError(args.Exception.ToString());
}
```

Do I actually need to call `await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message)` in my `messageHandler`, though?  I'm in `ReceiveAndDelete` mode so that should immediately delete the message from the ASB queue upon retrieval, but is `CompleteMessageAsync()` still needed in order to remove it from the local queue?  Or can I just remove that call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `CompleteMessageAsync` as the message will automatically be deleted once delivered.

In fact, I remember that calling this method actually throws an error when the message was fetched in `ReceiveAndDelete` mode.